# Irregular GATT_INVALID_HANDLE error on python GATT server

Tags: python, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am facing a problem with my flutter app accessing a GATT python endpoint. Sometimes, I do receive the following error message reading a characteristic on my remote machine (RPI 3b):
`Unhandled Exception: Exception: GenericFailure<CharacteristicValueUpdateError>(code: CharacteristicValueUpdateError.unknown, message: "GATT exception from MAC='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', status 1 (GATT_INVALID_HANDLE), type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}. (Look up status 0x01 here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.0_r1/stack/include/gatt_api.h)")`

I had a look at the link, but there is just the actual name of the error which is GATT_INVALID_HANDLE. The docs are not quite helpful...
For some reason it does work sometimes after restarting both the GATT server and the app several times.

Does anyone faced such an issue with BLE?

Best and thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear from your question which end the error is. Have you used a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool (e.g. [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)) to test the Python GATT server? Does `service bluetooth status` show errors on the RPi? `sudo btmon` will give very low level debug on the RPi.

Comment: In addition to the above, it would be useful if you shared the GATT table and the handle of the characteristic that you are trying to write to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.